# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'deleted "" ' - Django Generic DeleteView

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I've been trying to delete this model object but i keep getting this error:

`Field 'id' expected a number but got 'deleted template'`

I tried deleting the object from the admin side *(thinking it is a problem with my view)* but the error remain the same.

models

```
class TransactionalTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=30)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('role'))
    content = models.TextField(_('body'))
    category= models.CharField(_('category'), max_length=10, choices=CATEGORIES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mail_and_sms:template_list')

    def get_role(self):
        return self.role
```

views

```
class TemplateDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = TransactionalTemplate
    template_name = 'template_confirm_delete.html'
    success_message = _('was sucessfully deleted')


    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(request, f'{self.get_object()} {self.success_message}')
        self.get_object().delete()
        return redirect('mail_and_sms:template_list')
```

**EDIT**

Below is the traceback

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1772, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'deleted template') was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c/mail_and_sms/views.py", line 75, in dispatch
    return super(TemplateDeleteView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 218, in post
    return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c/mail_and_sms/views.py", line 67, in delete
    self.get_object().delete()
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 938, in delete
    return collector.delete()
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 322, in delete
    {field.name: value}, self.using)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 107, in update_batch
    self.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(NO_RESULTS)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1492, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1131, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1458, in as_sql
    val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 939, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 821, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2365, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/abdoul/Desktop/DevWork/c_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    ) from e

Exception Type: ValueError at /app/mailandsms/template/delete/9/
Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'deleted template'.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error.

Comment: @solarissmoke thanks for checking this out, i did add the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to understand where the problem was coming from.

There's a `ForeignKey` pointing to `TransactionalTemplate` model with `on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT` and `default='deleted template'`. it was defined as below:

```
class Outbox(models.Model):
    template = models.ForeignKey(TransactionalTemplate, 
               on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='deleted template', verbose_name=_('template')) ---- > here
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('recipients'))
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subject = models.CharField(_('subject'), max_length=255)
    message = models.TextField(_('message'))
```

when deleting a `TransactionalTemplate` object that is related to another object in `Inbox` model django tries to maintain the related object by setting it's value to whatever is set as the value of `default`, it expects a number `(int)` to be the default but all it could found was the string `'deleted template'` therefore raising `ValueError`.

so all i did to get rid of the error was:

- change `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` to `on_delete=models.CASCADE`
- remove `default='deleted template'`
- `./manage.py makemigrations` and `migrate`
- and finally edit migration file to change the initial default value to a number

Answer (score 0):

**solved**
according to your error :

```
Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'deleted template'.
```

you have to send number for id parameter in your view but you send the wrong string value "deleted template"

change your input values. and **test again**.